# Powershell generate System.Type out of String

Tags: .net, powershell, types, reflection

I am dynamically generating .net objects of a certain type like this `$MyType=([System.Type]::GetType("System.String")`
This works fine for standard .net objects.

I now created a custom class like this

```
class InstanceName
{
    [String] hidden $Val
    InstanceName([String]$CVal)
    {
        $this.Val=$CVal
    }
}
```

Here, this method does not work as powershell cannot find the type.
`$MyType=([System.Type]::GetType("InstanceName")`

Any idea how I can get a System.Type of a custom PS class?

Thx!

Comment: `$InstanceName = [InstanceName]`

Comment: In short: If you know the type name ahead of time, use a _type literal_ (`[SomeType]`). If the type name is stored in a _string_, cast it to `[type]`: `[type] 'SomeType'` (or use `'SomeType'  -as [type]`). See the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `-as` type conversion operator:

```
$instanceNameType = 'InstanceName' -as [type]

# test the type reference
$instanceNameType::new("")
```

Comment: `[type]'InstanceName'` works as well.